# How to open modal with multiple buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modal and I want to open it with more than one button.

First button (in 'Diamont Packet') work, this open the modal, but the other buttons don't work. The ids of buttons are all named `id="detail"`.

How to make it work all the buttons, videlicet all the buttons to open the modal?

This is my full code https://jsfiddle.net/hxhjyhpv/1/.

This is my js code:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
var btn = document.getElementById("detail"); 
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: ids must be different

Comment: ok, but how to open same modal with more more buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's should be unique on the page. Simply add some classes, and use `document.querySelectorAll` to fetch an array of buttons, and you're good to go.

See my updated jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hxhjyhpv/5/).

```
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.pack.detail'); 
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

[].forEach.call(btns, function(el) {
  el.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
  }
})
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. This code work perfect on Chrome, but it doesn't work on Firefox. Why..?

Comment: Try my updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hxhjyhpv/5/). It seems that you can't forEach through a nodelist on firefox.

Comment: Thank you so much. This code work well! https://jsfiddle.net/hxhjyhpv/5/